# Machine Learning - how can I get the ranked list of classification?

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I'm using machine learning for text classification.
I used WEKA and I could easily get the result by Naive Bayes.

But what I want to get is, not only the most probable class, but also the second probable case, the third probable case, and so on.
How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the distribution of all classes with the method `[distributionForInstance(instance)][1]`.

To use it

1. Train/Load your classifier => `cls`
2. Create an Instance for classification => `instance`
3. `double[] probabilities = cls.distributionForInstance(instance);`